# Split function won't split Python

Tags: python, split

In the example bellow, `page_numb.text` yields the string "pp. 1–25". I am trying to assign the "25" to a variable. For some reason this gets passed to a list as is. It doesn't split at the separator "-" but returns one string object in the list: "pp. 1–25".

```
page_numb = page_numb.text
final_page_numb = page_numb.split("-")
final_page_numb = final_page_numb[-1]
print(final_page_numb)
```

Comment: You may be dealing with an `em dash`    `-` and `—` are not the same thing

Comment: @Chris beat me to it - I copied the character in the OP's introductory paragraph and pasted it into an online unicode converted, and it is indeed em dash (U+2013). If the OP has copy-pasted that directly from the variable's content, that's the problem.

Comment: @Chris I just tried it... didn't work

Comment: try using  res = page_num.str.split('-')

Comment: @OliverPrislan error message: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'`

Answer (score 2):

`–` is not the same as `-`.

`page_numb.text` yields "pp. 1–25" which contains an em dash. Change it to a normal dash and you'll be fine.

Or replace `-` (normal dash) with `–` (em dash) and the value from `page_numb.text` will be split.

```
page_numb = page_numb.text
final_page_numb = page_numb.split("–")
final_page_numbs = final_page_numb[-1]
print(final_page_numbs)
```

Comment: I can't change it, it is dynamically scraped from a webdriver. Also I can't first assign it to a string in a variable and then use indexing because it can be anything from one to three digits.

Comment: Also I have tried with an em dash (`—`) as a separator and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1** Try with `re.search()`

```
import re
page_numb = "pp. 1–25"
final_page_numb = re.search('\d+$', page_numb)[0]
print(final_page_numb) # 25
```

**Option 2** Try with `re.split()`

```
page_numb = "pp. 1–25"
final_page_numb = re.split('[^\d]', page_numb)[-1]
print(final_page_numb) # 25
```

Comment: this returned "5" and I am not sure what you did so not sure how to adjust it.

Comment: regexp `\d+$` matches all the digits at the end of the string - see https://regex101.com/r/xsRSpC/1. Also it can be done with `re.split` (option 2 in the answer), where separator is `not a digit`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the answers/comments before, this was indeed an em dash. Weirdly enough when I typed the em dash using my keyboard ( Option + Shift + Minus in Mac keyboard), it didn't work. When I copied one from one of the returned strings, it worked. I guess there are different types of em dashes.